# Possible to ask "git mergetool" to automatically keep trying other files even if merging one file fails?

Tags: git, mergetool

I am trying to build a custom mergetool for git that knows more about specific files than git does.

This program will analyze the files that pop up during a merge conflict and for some of them, in some specific cases, it will know how to handle them successfully.

I execute this tool like this:

```
git mergetool --tool=auto
```

This successfully runs my program.

However, if the program fails to merge a file, and thus exits with a non-zero exit code I get this prompt from git:

```
Continue merging other unresolved paths [y/n]? n
```

Is there a way for me to configure git, or return a specific exit code, that tells git to just keep trying the rest of the files without user intervention?

ie. something like:

```
git mergetool --tool=auto --continue-always
```

or some magic exit code that means the same (or any other way to do the same)?

I've configured my mergetool with "trustExitCode = true" if that matters.

The ultimate goal would be that if a merge conflict occurs, I would first run the automagic program, and then use a normal mergetool, like KDiff3 or Beyond Compare, to merge the rest of the files manually.

Answer (score 0):

> something like `git mergetool --tool=auto --continue-always`, or some magic exit code that means the same (or any other way to do the same)?

No, unless you would consider modify [`git-mergetool.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/03e904cbd600afee7a39160aabc79a628916eecc/git-mergetool.sh#L494-L504) directly.

The only improvement on the prompt comes with Git 2.19 (Q3 2018): before, "`git mergetool`" stopped and gave an extra prompt to continue after the last path has been handled, which did not make much sense.

See [commit d651a54](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d651a54b8a22a307f5b061ba50c5348ae31e861c) (13 Aug 2018) by [Nicholas Guriev (`mymedia2`)](https://github.com/mymedia2).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 03e904c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/03e904cbd600afee7a39160aabc79a628916eecc), 20 Aug 2018)</sup>

> ### `mergetool`: don't suggest to continue after last file
>
> Eliminate an unnecessary prompt to continue after failed merger, by not calling the `prompt_after_failed_merge` function when only one iteration remains.
>
> Uses positional parameters to count files in the list to make it easier to see if we have any more paths to process from within the loop.